# MuleSoft - access data in db query in java component

Tags: java, mule, mule-component

Using MuleSoft to do some data transformations.  Relatively new to it and the Java language itself.  After many attempts of googling, thought I'd ask here.

Pulling data from an 11g Oracle database.  I have a database query being sent into a MuleMessage.  The output of the db query, according to AnyPoint studio, is List.

I can successfully call a java component in the form of an event.  Bit lost on how to extract the contents of the payload to look at the data though.  Really I'd like to add the values into another list map to do further processing.

Here is my db Query:

```
select name, country
from test_customer a, test_country b
where a.id = b.id
```

I want to put capture the name and country, and put it into my map.  The map then goes into a list of maps.

```
package org.mule.transformers;
import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;
import org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException;
import org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class myTransformer implements Callable{
@Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {

        MuleMessage message = eventContext.getMessage();
        Object payload = new Object();
        List<Map<String,String>> myList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();  //list of maps
        Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();    //map that holds

        String test;
        String test2;

        payload = message.getPayload();

        test = message.getInboundProperty("name");
        test2 = message.getInboundProperty("country");

        myMap.put(test, test2);

        myList.add(myMap);

        return myList;
    }
}
```

I guess I just don't know how to properly reference the MuleMessage variable properly to pull such data.  Documentation hasn't been helpful, or I've just been reading the wrong stuff.

Do I have to use MEL to do this?
Or can I just use some java functions to get this done?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Nuno's answer should work for what you're asking.  However, you'll probably have an easier time transforming your database results using some of the built in Mule components instead of a java component.  How do you want the data to look after your component executes?

Comment: Ultimately I'm wanting this to be some properly structured XML based off of some complex XSD files I have.  The problem is when it comes to mapping one-to-many relationships.  If I have a single customer that belongs to multiple countries, I don't have any real easy way of using the DataMapper component mule offers.  So, it's use XSL to correctly rebuild the one-to-many results as they come across in XML, or just do this in java where I have more control over what kind of "inbound object" gets fed to the data mapper.

Comment: DataMapper has lookups, which make it fairly easy to build hierarchical structures out of other things.  You can definitely do it in java, but you might end up preferring the java that mule already has :)  Another approach you can take is to go part of the way with java (say, result set List<Map> to your domain model) and the rest of the way with Mule, by using JAXB with <object-to-xml-transformer> and then an xslt transformer.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I'm going to go work this problem here within the next few days and keep this in my back pocket... won't forget it!  I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

The results of the query (if you are using the database connector) are in the payload and not in the inbound properties. So you are "searching" the results in the wrong place.

Probably the results are in the `List<Map<String,Object>>` format, so you need to do something like:

```
List<Map<String,Object>> results = (List<Map<String,Object>>) message.getPayload();

Map<String, Object> firstRow = results.get(0);

test = firstRow.get("name");
test2 = firstRow.get("country");
```

However, you should debug your component and inspect what is the right type of the payload.

Answer (score 0):

the output of db component will be ListOfMap objects.
In the java class which implements Callable interface
the output from DB component can access via below
`List<Map<String,Object>> results = (List<Map<String,Object>>) eventContext.getMessage().getPayload();`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below format...

```
public void AnalyseArray(ArrayList<Integer> array) {
    // Do something
}
...
ArrayList<Integer> A = new ArrayList<Integer>();
AnalyseArray(A);
```